# Blazor Server Side Concurrent User

Tags: blazor-server-side

We have developed ebanking app in blazor server.We had tested the app in local server.Apps worked as expected without performance degrade.Now we are hosting app in production server.We are more concerned that Can blazor handle multiple concurrent request? How can we test concurrent request in blazor?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your number of concurrent users on a single server is currently limited to 100,000.  I hope that will be enough. :D

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should create a web API with Blazor and then You can use JMeter for testing Blazor server web API with a high number of concurrent requests.
Here are Jmeter results[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9EBa.png)